# Accessing VPN URL with CasperJS

Tags: javascript, web-crawler, casperjs, vpn

I have a script written with CasperJS to perform an automated task at a URL, but the URL is hidden behind a VPN, so when I execute the script I get a 401 error.

I can access the URL using a normal browser and I've connected to the VPN, but still get a 401.

Anyone know how to get CasperJS/PhantomJS to see my machine's VPN connection?